# IIS features availiable to WindowsServer 08 R2 Standard vs WindowsServer 08 R2 Web

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a difference between installable IIS features (specifically Smooth Streaming) depending on which WindowsServer 08 R2 edition is installed?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference in IIS features between the editions.